# Azure DevOps Restore Solution Fails

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am having a hard time trying to detect what can be failing with the Restore Solution action in Azure DevOps Pipelines. My yaml file looks like:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- none

pr:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xxxxx/xxxxx
  dotNetVersion: '7.x'
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  project: '**/xxxxx.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'AnyCPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/xxxxx/xxxxx/build/bin/Release/net7.0/'

stages:
- stage: prepare_artifact
  displayName: 'Prepare Artifact'
  jobs:
  - job: "Setup"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Nuget Tool Installer'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Restore Solution'
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: $(dotNetVersion)

    - script: |
        dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      workingDirectory: $(buildPath)
      displayName: 'Build'

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        Contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: 'xxxxx'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

This pipeline was working until last week, but suddenly this week stop working in the Restore Solution step. If I restore the solution in my local machine, no errors are displayed.

The solution contains several projects, not all of them use nuget. Particularly the one that is failing is schemas.njsproj which is a NodeJs project so doesn't require the use of nuget at all.
The Log of the failed action is:

```
Starting: Restore Solution
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
Version      : 2.222.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
==============================================================================
/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/schemas/schemas.njsproj(82,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/vluonfw6.ai5.nugetrestore.targets(425,5): warning : Skipping restore for project '/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/schemas/schemas.njsproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/8pyejbwc.yrr.nugetinputs.targets]

Detected NuGet version 6.7.0.127 / 6.7.0+b46f5f64159a81d930ac8cdfde96e76f90796c62.b46f5f64159a81d930ac8cdfde96e76f90796c62
/usr/bin/mono /opt/hostedtoolcache/NuGet/6.7.0/x64/nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name NuGetOrg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -ConfigFile /home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/tempNuGet_4597108.config
Package source with Name: NuGetOrg added successfully.
/usr/bin/mono /opt/hostedtoolcache/NuGet/6.7.0/x64/nuget.exe restore /home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/pipelines.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile /home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/tempNuGet_4597108.config
NuGet Version: 6.7.0.127
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from '/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
/usr/bin/msbuild "/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/8pyejbwc.yrr.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/vluonfw6.ai5.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:DisableCheckingDuplicateNuGetItems="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="/opt/hostedtoolcache/NuGet/6.7.0/x64/nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/" /p:RestoreConfigFile="/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/tempNuGet_4597108.config" /p:SolutionDir="/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/" /p:SolutionName="pipelines" /p:RestoreBuildInParallel="False" /p:RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets="False"
NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
  at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.GetProjectReferencesAsync (NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildToolset msbuildToolset, System.String[] projectPaths, System.Int32 timeOut, NuGet.CommandLine.IConsole console, System.Boolean recursive, System.String solutionDirectory, System.String solutionName, System.String restoreConfigFile, System.String[] sources, System.String packagesDirectory, NuGet.ProjectModel.RestoreLockProperties restoreLockProperties) [0x0048e] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync (System.String[] projectsWithPotentialP2PReferences, System.String solutionDirectory, System.String solutionName, System.String configFile) [0x0012b] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync (NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand+PackageRestoreInputs packageRestoreInputs) [0x000e5] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0 
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/schemas/schemas.njsproj(82,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/vluonfw6.ai5.nugetrestore.targets(425,5): warning : Skipping restore for project '/home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines/schemas/schemas.njsproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [/tmp/NuGetScratchvsts/8pyejbwc.yrr.nugetinputs.targets])
##[error]Packages failed to restore
Finishing: Restore Solution
```

Do you know what can be happening? What should I do to restore the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bother reading the error message, but I strongly, strongly advise you to avoid `NuGetToolInstaller` and `NuGetCommand` unless you absolutely need nuget.exe. Since you're building with `-script: dotnet build`, I advice you to also restore with the `dotnet` CLI: `-script: dotnet restore`

Note that `dotnet build` will do an implicit restore, so you can choose to not have any restore step in your build. However, if you want more quickly know the difference between a restore failure and build failure, so keep the two tasks separate, you can also consider adding `--no-restore` to your `dotnet build` command. If you only have a small number of projects in your solution (or no solution, just a single project), then the peformance difference won't be noticable. However, NuGet's own NuGet.sln with nearly 100 projects takes multiple seconds for MSBuild to evaluate, so a needless restore wastes CI build minutes.